# Deeplinking schema and path prefix behaviour issue

Tags: android, applinks, android-deep-link

Hi in am my android application I am trying to implement app deep linking. I found following behaviour:

Scenario 1:

```
<data
android:host=“abc.com"
android:path="/"
android:scheme="https" />
<data
android:host=“abc.com"
android:pathPrefix="/care"
android:scheme="https" />

 In this case google search behaviour as follows: 
 If I search for **abc**
 it gives me app chooser with my application listed in it. 
 If I search for **abc /care** 
 it gives me app chooser with my application listed in it.
 If I go to abc.com in mobile browser it goes to mobile website 
 abc.com. Now in that web page if I click on web link which redirects 
 to abc.com/care that point it is not giving option to open my 
 application. I believe it should give me chooser with my application 
 as option.
```

Scenario 2:

```
<data
android:host=“abc.com"
android:scheme="https" />
<data
android:host=“abc.com"
android:pathPrefix="/care"
android:scheme="https" />

In this case please check data for first deep link.
In this case google search behaviour as follows: 
If I search for **abc**
it is not giving me app chooser option and directly redirects abc.com.
My expectation is it should give me app chooser with my application 
option. 
If I search for **abc /care** 
It gives me app chooser with my application listed in it.
If I go to abc.com in mobile browser it goes to mobile website 
abc.com. Now in that web page if I click on web link which redirects 
to abc.com/care that point it gives me app chooser with my application 
listed in it.
```

Both the scenarios works differently. Expected behaviour for me it should as app chooser with my application listed in it. Am I missing any thing or Is this the expected behaviour of it?

Comment: "Now in that web page if I click on web link which redirects to abc.com/care that point it is not giving option to open my application. I believe it should give me chooser with my application as option" -- that behavior is up to the developer of the Web browser. There are *many* Web browsers for Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for quick response. Why the behaviour change happened when I add "android:path="/" " in my case?